# Is there a way to turn the text of a <content> into an array?

Tags: polymer

I have simple element that has an unordered list with three `<li>` in it.  At the moment I have created a bound attribute for each li in the unordered list.

Here is what I did:
http://jsbin.com/degoba/1/

Is there way I can us the `<content>` tag and turn anything in the content tag into an array?

Basically instead of doing this:

```
<resume-sk sk1="test" sk2="test1" sk3="test2"></resume-sk>
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
<resume-sk>test,test1,test2</resume-sk>
```

any help would greatly be appreciated

Comment: can you use js/jQuery?

Comment: can't you pass it a list then iterate around that inside the element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read this.textContent to get the text content of the node. I believe it's also possible to react to changes to the textContent but I can't find that in the docs at the moment.

Here's a jsbin: http://jsbin.com/nafovezi/1/edit

Comment: peter if I wanted to could I break up the text node array?  example I wanted sk[0] to put in a front of a sentences but I wanted sk[1] in the back of a sentences?

Comment: Sorry I don't think I understand, can you clarify your question?

Comment: <resume-sk>test,test1,test3</resume-sk> you showed how to take the text in the content and split it up by using "'" as a divider.  but is there a way to specify each part of the army going to a different place with in the element? I would want to specify  test1 going to one place in the element and test2 going to another.

Comment: in the template you could use {{sks[0]}} {{sks[1]}} etc. More info: http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/expressions.html

Comment: Thank you again Peter (I apologize for the delay)